# Bounded cumulative sum in python without looping

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, cumulative-sum

I need to perform a cumulative sum with bounds - kind of like the charge state of a capacitor.  It can't go above its maximum charge, and can't go below 0.  Something like:

```
Initial  Cumulative Sum Constrained Sum
 1        1               1
 7        8               8
 5        13              10
 -8       5               2
 -7       -2              0
 3        1               3
```

I have a piece of code:

```
charge_0 = 0
for i in range (1, len(charge_discharge)):
    charge_1 = min(battery_size,max(0,(charge_0+charge_discharge[i])))
    StorageSOC.append(charge_1)
    charge_0 = charge_1
```

It works faster than some other options, but I know it is not optimized.  A simple cumulative sum is orders of magnitude faster, so I am sure there is a better way to do this.  I can't just apply a clip at the bounds.  What is the right way to do this without the for loop?

Comment: What is your data structure? Is it a list-of-lists, or is it something more suited to doing fast parallel data operations like a pandas dataframe

Comment: Because clipping element N affects all the sums thereafter.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890124/pandas-dataframe-running-sum-with-reset/32891081#32891081

Comment: Pranav: Right now I have the data as a list since I am looping and looking up indices in an array slows the process.  However, I'm not tied to any particular format.  The question is related to the post you mentioned, and I saw that when searching earlier. However, that involves a reset that can be accomplished via groupby. I don't think this can use groupby (unless I'm missing something).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need both old and new.  And you're skipping element 0.  This is a tiny bit faster, but I don't believe you can eliminate the loop.

```
charge = 0
for delta in charge_discharge:
    charge = min(battery_size,max(0,charge+delta))
    StorageSOC.append(charge)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll make that change.  However, I think there has got to be a solution using something like itertools.  I just can't figure out what it would look like.

Comment: `itertools` is just syntax sugar for a `for` loop.  You might be able to write it more compactly, but it will execute in the same time.

Comment: As I implemented the solution I realized your improvement comes from you correctly removing the indexing I had left in. I inherited the code and had removed most of those issues, I missed that one though.

Answer (score 0):

In the example, j0 and j1 are not defined. no cumsum involved in this piece, please refer a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the correct use of a question

This can be faster using vectorial approach on numpy or pandas, both have cumsum operation.

Comment: Thank you for noting the j0 and j1.  I haven't posted many questions here, those were placeholders in the original code and I didn't fix that in the post.  I have corrected that error in my post.  However, cumsum does not do what I want it to do.  The cumsum performs a cumulative sum, I need the sum to be clipped.  What I was looking for is a vectoral approach that allows clipping.

Comment: Can this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58518211/cumulative-sum-in-numpy-array-with-condition-for-stop  help you?